# Did the Prophet (may peace and blessinhs be upon him) make dua for his people?

Tags: dua, prophets

Did our Noble Prophet (may peace and blessings be upon him) make duas for the Quraysh who hit him and called him bad names (magician, liar, poet, madman)

Comment: My question is what kind of du'a you mean? Positive asking Allah to forgive them or negative asking Allah to I.e destroy them. Both kinds may exist.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, he did.

When the Quraysh were dying of famine, the Prophet (ﷺ) [prayed for rain](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/15/15) to ease their misery.

Another example is the Prophet's (ﷺ) [dua](https://sunnah.com/urn/635590) for either Abu Jahl (staunch enemy) or Umar Ibn Al Khattab (not a Muslim at the time) to embrace Islam, which was answered when Umar Ibn Al Khattab (RA) was guided and became Muslim.

A [third example](https://sunnah.com/muslim/44/226) is the mother of Abu Huairah who insulted the Prophet (ﷺ) yet upon request the Prophet (ﷺ) prayed for her guidance and she ended up embracing Islam, making Abu Huraiah (RA) very happy.

The list of examples goes on.

Comment: Jazaki Allah khayran

Comment: The mother of Abu Hurairah is not from Quraish but from Daws. And the famine in the first hadith came from a prior du'a of the prophet too.

Comment: "the famine in the first hadith came from a prior du'a of the prophet too" - Your point being what, exactly? Doesn't change that he made the follow up dua I referenced to relieve them of their misery.

Comment: Abu Hurairah is from among "the Prophet's people" i.e., nation. This is how I answered the question.. based on those close to him/his followers and not specifically just from the Quraysh. FYI. It's not specified that Quraysh-only answers are being requested. Nevetheless, the first two are Quraish related.

Comment: @Muslimahياربالعالمين this is the wording of the question which anybody can read: "Did our Noble Prophet (may peace and blessings be upon him) make duas for **the Quraysh** who hit him and called him bad names (magician, liar, poet, madman)“

Comment: Please refrain from trying to force your interpretation of the question and rather ask the questioner if he wants Quraish only answers. You already struggled with one aspect of the question (is the dua positive or negative?), might as well seek clarification on the rest.